# Javascript override parseFloat but now doesn't see toFixed

Tags: javascript, parsefloat, overriding

Due to culture specifics, I recently overrode parseFlaot function with a custom implementation. Afterwards, everywhere where toFixed was used with parseFloat, failed with *Object doesn't support property or method 'toFixed'*

How can I chain the override to also allow for a custom implementation of toFixed?

Comment: You should never do that! Instead, create some utility function to attend your culture specific needs. If you start overwriting built-in stuff, you will get unexpected results.

Comment: While I totally agree, this is retrofitting existing sites to make it support a comma separator for certain cultures. parseFloat is everywhere. The only way short of replacing every parseFloat is to override the function in the master file. I store the original parseFloat in a var and even use it after formatting the number in the client side form.

Comment: What do you return from your `parseFloat` ? Or better, could you share the implementation with us ?

Comment: Conceptually, I convert the server side cultural number format to the client side and then use the original parseFloat. Then return to the caller in the form it is expecting given the server side culture info. I found the solution via adding to the String prototype 'toFixed' and casting the return value to String. It works well for what I need it for and no code had to be changed in the site.

Comment: Please note that this 'fix' will only needs to last for roughly 6 months as we are switching over to a new MVC platform and have made strides to deal with our international clients since the code base I'm retrofitting was developed. Not my normal practice to handle this in such a way.